# Capillary rise of water in a capillary tube

Tags: newtonian-gravity, surface-tension, capillary-action

While I was selfstudying capillary rise I came to a point thinking how the meniscus in both ends of a water drop in a capillary tube would appear if it were falling under gravity then I built my hypothesis. but no idea whether it's correct. Please, someone who's interested in regards of this, kindly explain us how it happens really.

What I thought was, when falling under gravity the $mg$ of water can be considered zero which makes the  surface tension that creates the upper meniscus, be cancelled of by the tension of the below meniscus which makes both menisci (up and down) similar in shape. But I then felt like "can there be tension while falling under gravity? shouldn't tension be zero? so would the meniscus be just flat then?"  please explain someone who knows.

Answer (score 0):

The [meniscus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meniscus_(liquid)) occurs under gravity because the energy of the glass-water interface is different (probably lower) than the energy of the glass-air interface. (Material surfaces and interfaces always cost energy because the bonds are less satisfied there than in the bulk.) Water tends to wet hydrophilic glass, but gravity imposes a penalty to the water being lifted higher. The final shape is the one that minimizes the total energy.

In free fall, without an effective gravitational force, the water would tend to shift at the sides to wet the glass more. The dominant penalty would now be the additional surface area of the water-air interface, and this would determine the degree to which the water coats the glass. Again, the final shape would be the one that minimizes the total energy. You might see the meniscus shift only slightly, or you might see the water coat the entire available glass surface. The major factor is the energy of that glass-water interface, which generally comes down to how that glass was manufactured and treated (i.e., its degree of hydrophilicity).

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge..